GitHub Action not triggering on schedule
Here's my code for a scheduled workflow every 5 minutes but it doesn't trigger. I do have my .github/workflows directory and yml file. My repo does allow to run Actions (checked in settings) and the workflow is in the main branch.
Any help is appreciated.
name: Order Processing

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/5 * * * *'

jobs:
  update_and_notify:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install gspread google-auth smtplib email dotenv
      
      - name: Run script
        env:
          ENCODED_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.ENCODED_CREDENTIALS }}
          SHEET_ID: ${{ secrets.SHEET_ID }}
          EMAIL_ADDRESS: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_ADDRESS }}
          EMAIL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_PASSWORD }}
          EMAIL_SERVER: ${{ secrets.EMAIL_SERVER }}
          PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        run: python order_confirmation.py


How are you confirming whether or not it runs?
